# Can I use spells/items using the champ icons on the left?

Tags: league-of-legends

I saw a YouTube video of a Shen player who tried to ult an ally using the champ icons on the left, for my disgrace he didn't make it in time, but it is obvious he tried that for a good reason (which is that it *is* possible).

So my inquiries instantaneously became:

- Can Shen ult this way? (if Yes, does it work with smart casting?)
- Can I also use items or range-spells (e.g Nidalee heal or Zilean bombs) if my allies are within range? (**bonus:** if they are not in range, will my champion walk towards them?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the portraits can be used to target any non-skillshot ability, regardless of range.

edit: They can also be used to target the champion period, so you can see their stats and item build.

second edit: If a champion out of range is targeted using the portraits on the left, you *will* walk to that champion to cast your spell\ability.

Comment: Will you walk towards them if they are out of range?

Comment: @SadlyNot im going to test this in game to be sure, i consistently forget to do so every game >.< I'll return with an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The mini-icons are useful to :

- select the champion with a right click
- casting something on the champion (if the range distance is met) using the click
- smartcasting on the champion (if the range distance is met) using hover + smartcast key

This is very practical in cases like:

- The champion you want to target (e.g. for a shield) is to close to a enemy unit (Nashor, Dragon) and you don't want to use the offensive version of the spell (e.g. when playing Lulu)
- Targeting a champion which is in melee with other allies and enemies (though it can be longer to actually target the icon than being precise on the screen. But it's "safer" in the sense you can be mistaken)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it works with smart casting. You can click on portraits to cast, and if you didn't know, you can hold alt + Q/W/E/R to self-cast a spell or item (1-6).